# Permission issues installing npm on OSX

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having issues installing the node package manager "npm".

On the [website](http://npmjs.org/) it prompts you to do a 1 line install as follows...

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

This spits out the following install error...

```
$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7184  100  7184    0     0  27012      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 39256
tar=/usr/bin/tar
version:
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.0.106.tgz
0.4.11
1.0.106
cleanup prefix=/usr

All clean!
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.72890/package/cli.js" "rm" "npm" "-gf"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.72890/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.4.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.72890/package/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
npm ERR! error installing npm@1.0.106 Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back npm@1.0.106 Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.72890/package/cli.js" "install" "-gf"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.72890/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.4.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.72890/package/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

After [googling around](http://www.hacksparrow.com/two-common-nodejs-npm-permission-denied-errors-on-linux.html) it looked like this is a common issue and the way of fixing it is to just run the same command prefaced with sudo.

Strangely, this doesn't seem to work in my case. This what happens if I run the same command sudo'd.

```
$ sudo curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
Password:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7184  100  7184    0     0   9974      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 40359
tar=/usr/bin/tar
version:
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.0.106.tgz
0.4.11
1.0.106
cleanup prefix=/usr

All clean!
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.81519/package/cli.js" "rm" "npm" "-gf"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.81519/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.4.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.81519/package/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
npm ERR! error installing npm@1.0.106 Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back npm@1.0.106 Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.81519/package/cli.js" "install" "-gf"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.81519/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.4.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/mn/8q6c34bj67xbxk08dwlsb_y40000gn/T/npm.81519/package/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
It failed
```

I'm drawing a blank here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

It's `sh` that needs the permissions, not `curl`.

Comment: cool, just needed to do this myself and this was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
git clone http://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
sudo make install
```